# pg_backup.sh: "No such file or directory" for pg_backup.config

Tags: bash, postgresql, shell, backup, dump

In order to create backups of a postgres DB, I downloaded the backup scripts provided [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux).

I created a `pg_backup.config` which is located in `/etc`. Put `pg_backup.sh` in `/usr/local/bin`. When trying to run the script, like so:

```
$ pg_backup.sh -c /etc/pg_backup.config
```

... I get the following error message:

```
/usr/local/bin/pg_backup.sh: line 27: /usr/local/bin/pg_backup.config: No such file or directory
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Obviously, the script tries to load the configuration from `/usr/local/bin/pg_backup.config`, although I specified `/etc/pg_backup.config` as config input. How can I specify from where to load the configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That script seems to accept a config file on the command line but then *also* requires one to exist next-to the binary itself (and finds that location in a less than robust way<sup>[1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028)</sup>).

The script is just broken.

The very first thing it does is parse its command line options (using a manual `while` loop). As it does so it removes them from the positional parameters (using `shift`). It stops that loop when there are no more positional parameters (when `[ $# -gt 0 ]` is no longer true).

Immediately upon draining the positional parameters it then goes and checks the count of positional parameters **again** (`if [ $# = 0 ]; then`) and when, inevitably, it finds that there are no more positional parameters it attempts to source its default configuration file.

The `pg_backup_rotated.sh` script, in contrast, has a much more reasonable mechanism for loading a configuration file (though it still uses the less-than robust way of finding the location for the default config file).

Comment: Didn't notice that the code in `pg_backup_rotated.sh` was different. I will stick to this one, as it seems to work in my case. Thank you for the detailed explanation!